# Manage multiple git release branches for multiple customers

Tags: git, branch

My company has a piece of software we sell to multiple customers.
But every customer have some different requirements (more than just *"Put our logo here"*). The core is the same for all of them, but some does not need certain modules, others need them all including modifications.

I would like to manage all of this in a single git repository so I have the same core for them all, but I'm not quite sure how to do this the best way.

I read about [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow), and how to make a single project [succesful regarding branches](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), which gives a branch model like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nvie.com](http://nvie.com/img/git-model@2x.png))</sub>

Now, we have multiple customers, and therefore multiple `release` branches (`release-customer1-v1.2`, `release-customer2-v3.8`, ...), but they all build on the same `master` branch.

Are there any strategy to manage this chaos?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @AnimiVulpis. His/Her answer gave me a hint.
Here's my solution: (also base on the nvie's strategy)

1.Extract the exact common parts from project. Create a branch named shared/develop

2.Based on the shared/develop, creating a customer1's branch

```
git checkout -b local/customer1/develop origin/shared/develop
#push this new branch to remote
git push origin local/customer1/develop:origin/customer1/develop
git push origin local/customer1/develop:origin/customer1/master
```

3.Same with step 2. create other customers' branch.

4.All the common parts used for all customers should work on shared/develop branch.

4.All the feature development just for the customerN should work on its own customerN/develop branch.It should be note that all the customers' branches should merge from shared/develop branch before a new feature 
coding.

Comment: It sounds like a viable solution, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple and viable solution might be to have `develop` and `release` branches for every customer.

***Edit**: previously `develop` was called `master` in the sentence before, but I like develop better*

---

- All the common things would live in the shared `develop` branch
- Each customer would have it's own `develop` and `release` branches

You would have to take extra care to make changes that affect all customers in the shared `develop` and changes that only affect specific customers only on their respective branches.

---

### Scenario I

You develop **feature A** for **customer A**, and **feature B** for **customer B**.

**If those features do not share code** they should be kept in the respective `develop-*` branches, e.g. **feature A** will be developed in `develop-customer-A` and **feature B** in `develop-customer-B`

**If those features share code** the shared part should be developed on the shared `develop` and the parts specific to the customers in their respective branches `develop-*`

Comment: Scenario: I develop ``Feature A`` for customer A, and ``Feature B`` for customer B. They should both go into the ``Developer``-branch? Then the ``Master A`` will get ``Feature B`` as well, I assume (and wise-versa)?